# Update Mongoengine document without actively keeping track of the fields that changed

Tags: python, mongodb, updates, mongoengine

I read a lot of the questions & answers on SO regarding how to update a document in Mongoengine (and MongoDB), but my problem is that all of them recommend "manually" giving as parameter all the fields that one wants to update as a dict - e.g.

```
p.update(**{
    "set__name": "Hank",
    "set__address": "Far away"
```

})

My problems with this are the following:

1. I need to keep track of all the fields that modified
2. I need to specify as strings in a dict all the names of the fields that I want to update
3. I need to specify a modifier specific to the type of field I am modifying and the operation I do on that field.

Is there any way to update documents in Mongoengine/MongoDB using Python in a higher-level way? (To be more specific, I wish to update a document in MongoDB if it hasn't changed since I last read it from the DB.)

So my application is quite complex. I am often pass around an object *p* which corresponds to a document in the database, so that different methods modify fields of it, and then at the end of all the updates I want to save the modified document without having to worry which field has change and what modifier I need to use for it.

Any suggestion how I could do this or implement something to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you just want to call the [.save](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.save) method on the Document object after you have changed it (or on a new Document object with the right `_id` that you've created from whatever kind of thing `p` you have that represents a document in MongoDB).

Comment: Well, yes, except for the fact that if I do save() and the object modified in the meantime, I think those changes would be overwritten. So what I currently have is a version field => I update only if my query matches the _id and the version of the document. I am not sure if this is possible with save()

Comment: Use findAndModify (or some API wrapper around it) for versioning and then you can use save to update the whole document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the answer to my question: it seems that starting from mongoengine 0.8.5 they've added a new parameter to the save() function - called save_condition - which does exactly what I was asking about:

```
save_condition – only perform save if matching record in db 
                 satisfies condition(s) (e.g., version number)
```

(according to the documentation:
http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html)